# Installing JUCE on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, c++

I downloaded JUCE' zip file from its website: https://juce.com/get-juce/download

```
~/Downloads/JUCE$ ls
BREAKING-CHANGES.txt  ChangeList.txt  CMakeLists.txt  DemoRunner  docs  examples  extras  
LICENSE.md  modules  Projucer  README.md
```

I ran:
`sudo apt-get update -y`
and
`sudo apt-get install -y juce-tools`

These commands ran successfully.

I did run ./Projucer and it did open a GUI.

My problem is that I haven't installed anything particular related to JUCE. I just unzipped their file and ran ./Projucer.

How do I make sure that JUCE framework is properly installed and running?

It all seems too easy to be true.

Comment: I don't understand what you've done here. First, you download the pre-compiled Juce v6.0.1 binaries...then you install Juce v5.2.1 from the Ubuntu repos...and then go back and run v6.0.1 from your unzipped download directory. You don't need both.

Comment: @ajgringo619 having those pre compiled library means that I don't have to install anything? I simply have to run the executable of. /Projucer from the zip file?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything from the zip file at all, unless you need to use the latest version. What does `/usr/bin/Projucer` do?

Comment: @ajgringo619 It does open the GUI. Does it mean that it got installed by `juce-tools`?

Comment: Yes, no reason to have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need the latest version of any software, the preferred method to install programs is via your distro's repositories (as you did with the `sudo apt-get install -y juce-tools` command). This way, you will be sure to get security fixes when they become available.

You can remove the .zip and the files/folders it created upon unzipping.